# A pathfinding problem: how to tell water-road situation?

Tags: ios, swift, algorithm, path-finding, gameplay-kit

As you see, there is a map and I want to pathfinding to identify which cities are liked each other.

The yellow tiles in the map are the Land, and blue ones are the ocean.
The red font means there is a waterway, and the green font means there
is a road. The correct path should be linked as road-road, waterway-waterway,
road-harbor-waterway or waterway-harbor-road. Therefore,

2,6City can link to 2,4City via (2,6City)-(1,6)-(0,6)-(1,5)-(2,5)-(3,4Harbor)-(2,4City),

2,6City can link to 0,0City via (2,6City)-(1,6)-(0,6)-(1,5)-(2,5)-(3,4Harbor)-(2,4City)–
(1,4)-(0,3City)-(0,2)-(0,1)-(0,0City),

2,6City can link to 3,0City via (2,6City)-(1,6)-(0,6)-(1,5)-(2,5)-(3,4Harbor)-(3,3)–
(3,2)-(4,1Harbor)-(3,0City).

However, when I use GKGridGraph to create a map for Pathfinding, I don’t know how to
tell the situation that waterway is not accessible to road. You can see, I DON‘T want:

2,6City can link to 2,4City via (2,6City)-(2,5)-(2.4City) or

2,4City is linked to 2,2City because (2,4City)-(3,4Harbor)-(3,3)-(3,2)-(2,2City)

So, any suggestion? Thanks a lot.

[image]

Comment: I am not familiar with `GKGridGraph`. In general, I would try to use DFS (where you explore each path to its end) and implement the restrictions in the `getNeighbors` function. For example, only road and harbor are considered a neighbor of a road.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. This is a way to solve my problem but it seems a little complex because I need to maintain a new Grid. Anyway, thanks all the same.

Comment: _I need to maintain a new Grid_ I am not sure what you mean by that. Only one grid representation is needed.

Comment: well. I used GKGridGraph to create my map grid so that I can use findpath function by GKGridGraph to check if two tiles in the grid can connect or not. When I use DFS, first I have to realize DFS function by myself and then I need to build a new grid to tell DFS which tiles connected each other.  like: 
let graph = Graph()
let nodeA = graph.addNode("a")
let nodeB = graph.addNode("b")
graph.addEdge(nodeA, neighbor: nodeB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `GKGridGraph(fromStartingGridAt:width:height:diagonalsAllowed:)` to create your graph then every node has connections to each of its neighbors. So a better picture of your map would be this:

[image: Graph with all connections]

Since every node is connected it will find the shortest path which will pass through the water. To prevent that you need to remove the impossible connections. Your graph should look something like this:

[image: Graph with correct connections]

To achieve that you cam simply remove the unwanted connections from your graph using [`GKGraphNode.removeConnections(to:bidirectional:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gameplaykit/gkgraphnode/1427548-removeconnections)

This could be achieved by a function like this one:

```
func disconnect(_ a: vector_int2, _ b: vector_int2) {
    guard
        let first = grid.node(atGridPosition: a),
        let second = grid.node(atGridPosition: b)
    else {
        return
    }

    first.removeConnections(to: [second], bidirectional: true)
}
```

Depending on how you store and load your map a better solution probably would be to start with an empty graph and only add the necessary connections while loading the map.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have completed the codes based on your hint and it solved the problem. Thanks again.